# Image in related list in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, related-list, image-formula

I have a related list which displays a image-formula based field i.e. as per the formula it displays different images (icons). This works perfectly in desktop version but in salesforce1 it does not (there is no image rendered).

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately no workaround at this stage check out salesforce known issue here https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008aAEAAY